# IBM Bluemix Push Notification not working on the production mode

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services, ibm-cloud-plugin

Now I am woking on the ionic framework and integrating the IBM Bluemix Push Notification on the app. But I have a issue with production mode. When I install the app with development mobile provision, the app works well and I can receive the push message. But I try to build the ipa with release mode, I can not receive the push.
What do I need to do more any configuration or IBM Bluemix Push Notification can't work on the production mode with Cordova Plugin ?
Can anyone give any idea ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [MobileFirst Starter - Bluemix Push Notification failure in Production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008742/mobilefirst-starter-bluemix-push-notification-failure-in-production-mode/34009032#34009032)

It is likely that you have not configured your certificate on Bluemix while in Production mode. I would suggest following my answer in that question and setting your Bluemix environment to Production, and then configuring your push certificate after doing so and retrying your application.

If this does not work please provide your Bluemix application ID so we can do more investigation. Thanks